# CSS - I have a headless woman on my page. Z-index issue?

Tags: css, z-index

I have a new web site that has an image of a woman in the upper left corner. The image is in the perfect spot, but I can't get the top half of the image to be on top of the other layers.  This certainly seems a z-index issue.  I have tried every possible combination to get the top half of the image to show up. No luck.

Can you tell me why the top half of the woman doens't show up? How can I fix it?

You can access the page here:  http://i-treadmillreviews.com/

Also, I am building this site in FF and Chrome. I don't care about making it work in IE right now. I'll do IE tweaks as the very last thing. So, don't tell me that it works or doesn't work in IE, unless of course you are Bill Gates, in which case I have some strong words to share with you.

Comment: Nice design - you are gifted.

Comment: @Majid, the site is devoid of color right now. Color will be added dynamically by the administrator. Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: You couldn’t have waited six weeks and posted this on Hallowe’en?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: hidden` from `PageWrapper`.

Comment: How could you have POSSIBLY gotten that? I swear I just added it ten minutes ago is desperation. Now I take it out and it works?  You hit the nail on the head.  Thanks!!!

Comment: When you've spent as much time as I have swearing at CSS files you eventually learn something! Glad I could help

Comment: further to the overflow hidden issue, it's a common float fix to apply overflow hidden to something and this sort of problem can result from that fix applied elsewhere in a project